# facebook login using FBloginView not showing in ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios

i am trying create login button for facebook using FBloginView. 
Following is the code i wrote.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if(!loginview)
    loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions, user_photos,status_update"]]; // Whatever permissions you need

loginview.frame = self.view.bounds; //whatever you want

loginview.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginview];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

NSLog(@"Logged In");

}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
NSLog(@"user Id %@",user.id);

}
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
// Called after logout
NSLog(@"Logged out");
}
```

but its not showing login button. 
what is the problem with my code. in console am getting "Logged out".

Comment: refer this Link https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/HelloFacebookSample/HFViewController.m

Comment: yes. i referred it. i have that sample code. it is running fine. but in my code its not working..

Comment: What are the differences between that code and your code..

Comment: They are initializing like this.. FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init]; and some change in delegate implementation.. i think dont make much difference.. In app delegate they are using FBSession.activeSession, same like me... but its for ios 4, mine is ios 6..

Comment: i resolved it by adding FacebookSDKResources.bundle... Thank you..

Answer (score 6):

I had FacebookSDKResources.bundle added but still I got the error "Unknown class FBLoginView in interface builder" appearing in the xcode output pane.

To fix this I added the following line to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
[FBLoginView class];
```

This is explained in https://developers.facebook.com/ios/login-ui-control/

Answer (score 4):

As noted by @rajath above, the resolution is to add the FacebookSDKResources.bundle to your project.